# Cambiar valor de input segun checkbox con Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: Imagen de muestra]

Hola, estoy trabajando en un formulario y me dicen que necesitan agregar cinco checkboxs y cinco inputs, de modo que si selecciono el primer checkbox el valor del primer input sea de 100 pero si selecciono el segundo checkbox el valor del segundo input sea de 100, sin embargo si selecciono el primer checkbox y el segundo entonces el valor del primer y segundo input sea de 50 para ambos sumar 100 y asi sucesivamente, se que tengo que usar condicionales y agregar id a cada checkbox e input para detectarlos, y aunque se como hacerlo en la teoria no logro hacerlo funcionar en la practica, se como cambiar el valor del input segun el checkbox pero no se como ingresarlo dentro de condicionales, estoy usando el evento change para detectar cuando cambia el estado del checkbox

```
jQuery("#choice_6_11_1").on( 'change', function() {
            if( jQuery(this).is(':checked') ) {
                jQuery('#input_6_17').val("100")
            } else {
                jQuery('#input_6_17').val("0")
            }
        });
```

Comment: Y, si selecciona 3, 100 no es divisible por 3? qué debes elegir 33, 33 y 34? **comenta a tu profesor que existe el mínimo común múltiplo** de (1,2,3,4,5) = 60 y que le ponga un cero adicional si desea usar centenas para que las cifras cacen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se me ocurrió algo así!

Puedes agregar todos los checks e inputs que necesites, solo asegurate que el input tenga el id del check.

Saludos!

```js
//Obtenemos 2 arreglos de inputs
const checks = [...document.querySelectorAll('#checks input')]
const inputs =  [...document.querySelectorAll('#inputs input')]

//Seteamos la función "changeCheck" en el envento change de todos los checks
checks.forEach(check => check.addEventListener('change', e => changeCheck(e)))

const changeCheck = e => {
  const check = e.target
  const gValue = document.getElementById('globalValue').value
  
  if(gValue <= 0) return
  
  //Iteramos sobre todos los checks, si esta seleccionado devolvemos 1 sino 0.
  //Después sumamos. Ejemplo: 1 0 1 ---> 1 + 0 + 1 = 2
  const checkeds = checks.map(r => r.checked ? 1 : 0).reduce((x, j) => x + j)
  
  //Dividimos el valor global entre los checks seleccionados
  const newValue = gValue / checkeds
  
  //Iteramos sobre cada input
  inputs.forEach(input => {
  
    //Obtenenemos el check padre de acuerdo al atributo data-parent
    const parent = document.getElementById(input.dataset.parent)
    
    //Si el padre está seleccionado, seteamos el valor, sino, dejamos vacío
    if(parent.checked)
      input.value = newValue
    else
      input.value = ""
  })
}
```

```html
Inserte el valor a dividir:
<input type="number" id="globalValue">
<hr>
<div id="checks">
  <input id="check1" type="checkbox">
  <input id="check2" type="checkbox">
  <input id="check3" type="checkbox">
  <input id="check4" type="checkbox">
  <input id="check5" type="checkbox">
</div>
<div id="inputs">
  <input data-parent="check1"/>
  <input data-parent="check2"/>
  <input data-parent="check3"/>
  <input data-parent="check4"/>
  <input data-parent="check5"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu comentario, es justo lo que necesito.

Comment: De nada, márcala como aceptada, jaja. Saludos